# Showing $f$ constant if it is continuous and $f(2x) = f(x)$

Tags: functions, solution-verification, functional-equations

> Let $f$ be a continuous function such that $f(2x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f(x)$ is a constant function.

I want to know whether my proof for it is correct.

I proceeded by taking:
$$f(x)=f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=f\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)=\dots=f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$$

For any real number $x'\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$f(x')=f\left(\frac{x'}{2^n}\right)$$

We now take a limit on both sides:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x') = \lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{x'}{2^n}\right)$$

The sequence $\frac{x'}{2^n}$ converges to $0$. Hence we get, $f(x')=f(0)$ for all $x'\in \mathbb{R}$, implying $f(x)$ is a constant function.

Comment: It should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x')$, but aside from that, yes it's right. (Also, note that there's nothing special about $2$, more generally if $\lambda>0$ then an almost identical proof shows if for all $x$, $f(\lambda x) = f(x)$, then $f$ is constant)

Comment: Checks out to me.

Comment: Maybe for rigour, you can add one more step apart from the edit $x\rightarrow x'$ that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f\left(\frac{x'}{2^n}\right)= f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x'}{2^n}\right)$ which happens because $f$ is continuous and is a key part of why the proof works. It's sound anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\ f(x)=f(\frac{x}{2})=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{x}{{2}^{n}})$$
Now since $\ f(x)$ is a continuous function, it is continuous at $\ x=0$. Hence, by definition, $$\ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{x}{{2}^{n}})=f(0)$$
Therefore $$\ f(x)=f(0) \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Yes, your proof is correct. But make sure that you use the definition of continuity in this step $$\ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{x}{{2}^{n}})=f(0)$$ Hope it helps!